# Knockout adding a child object at runtime

Tags: knockout.js, parent-child

I'm quite new to knockoutjs and need some help with a parent-child like viewmodel issue.

```
var DailyItems = function (data) {
var p = this;
this.Day = ko.observable(data.Day);
this.Date = ko.observable(data.Date);
this.Required = ko.observable(data.Required);
this.RequiredActive = ko.observable(true);
this.SetupTime = ko.observable(data.SetupTime);
this.CloseTime = ko.observable(data.CloseTime);
this.MinHrsPerDay = ko.observable(data.MinHrsPerDay);
this.MaxHrsPerDay = ko.observable(data.MaxHrsPerDay);
this.MinWorkShift = ko.observable(data.MinWorkShift);
this.WorkSegments = ko.observableArray([]);
var records = $.map(data.WorkSegments, function (x) { return new WorkShift(p, x) });
this.WorkSegments(records);
this.EnableAdd = ko.observable(ko.toJS(this.WorkSegments).length < 8);
this.Add = function () {
    this.WorkSegments.push({
        Parent: p,
        ID: "",
        Day: data.Date,
        Location: UNIT_ID,
        Role: "",
        EmployeeRoles2: "[]",
        ShiftStart: "",
        ShiftEnd: "",
        LocationActive: true,
        RoleActive: true
    });
    this.EnableAdd(ko.toJS(this.WorkSegments).length < 8);
}
this.Delete = function (item) {
    this.WorkSegments.remove(item);
    this.EnableAdd(ko.toJS(this.WorkSegments).length < 8);
}
```

};

The child model is like follows:

```
var WorkShift = function (parent, data) {
var self = this;
this.Parent = ko.observable(parent);
this.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
this.Day = ko.observable(data.Day);
this.Location = ko.observable(data.Location);
this.Parent = ko.observable(0);
this.LocationActive = ko.observable(true);
this.RoleActive = ko.observable(true);
this.ShiftStart = ko.observable(data.ShiftStart);
this.ShiftEnd = ko.observable(data.ShiftEnd);
this.EmployeeRoles2 = ko.observableArray([{ "ID": 0, "Name": "Volume"}]);
this.Location.subscribe(function (branchId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: SERVER_PATH + '/WebServices/AttributeService.asmx/GetDataOnLocationChange',
        data: "{" + "clientId: '" + CLIENT_ID
                    + "', unitId: '" + branchId
                    + "', effectiveDate:'" + EFFECTIVE_DATE
                    + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (res) {
            var d = JSON.parse(res.d);
            self.EmployeeRoles2(d.Roles);
            if (d.IsSection == true) {
                self.RoleActive(false);
                self.Parent(d.Parent);
            }
            else if (d.IsRegularBranch == false) {
                self.RoleActive(false);
                self.LocationActive(false);
            }
            else {
                self.RoleActive(true);
                self.LocationActive(true);
            }
            var tasks = self.Parent().WorkSegments();
            //Requirement: for any day of the week, if there is more than one work segment
            //at different branches the required type should be set to 'On' and made disable
            if (tasks.length > 1) {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(tasks, function (i) {
                    if ((d.isSection == false && i.Location() != self.Location()) || (d.isSection == true && self.Parent() != i.Parent())) {
                        self.Parent().Required('O');
                        self.Parent().RequiredActive(false);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        self.Parent().Required('E');
                        self.Parent().RequiredActive(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: HandleLocationChangeError
    });
} .bind(this));
this.Role = ko.observable(data.Role);
this.TimeRangeTotal = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var timeRangetotal = 'T: 0';
    var startTime = parseInt(ko.toJS(this.ShiftStart));
    var endTime = parseInt(ko.toJS(this.ShiftEnd));
    if (!isNaN(startTime)) {
        var duration = endTime - startTime;
        var hrs = parseInt(duration / 100);
        var mins = duration % 100;
        if (mins == 55 || mins == 70 || mins == 85)
            mins = mins - 40; //addresses deducting from a total hour (e.g. 1400 - 845)
        timeRangetotal = "T: " + hrs + ":" + mins;
    }
    return timeRangetotal;
}, this);
```

}

Note that the Child object as a Dependent observable and a subscribe method. I want to add a child object at run-time, hence the Add() function in the DailyItems model. My issue is how to cater the subscribe method and the dependable observable in the Add() method?

Appreciate if someone can help.

Regards,
Chathu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I haven't got time for a full answer, but you should look at the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to turn your JS data into view models.

In your add method, you need to create a child view model, not just add a normal JS object to the WorkSegments array:

this.Add = function () {
    var data = {
        Parent: p,
        ID: "",
        Day: data.Date,
        Location: UNIT_ID,
        Role: "",
        EmployeeRoles2: "[]",
        ShiftStart: "",
        ShiftEnd: "",
        LocationActive: true,
        RoleActive: true
    };
    var child = new WorkShift(p, data);
    this.WorkSegments().push(child);

As an aside, you can change this code:

```
this.EnableAdd = ko.observable(ko.toJS(this.WorkSegments).length < 8);
```

to:

```
this.EnableAdd = ko.computed(function() { this.WorkSegments().length < 8; });
```

Comment: It worked, thanks for your help. I'll follow your advice on using mapping plugin. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code version. It works like a beauty now :)

```
this.Add = function () {
    var data = {
        Parent: p,
        ID: "",
        Day: this.Date,
        Location: UNIT_ID,
        ParentBranch:0,
        Role: "",
        EmployeeRoles2: "[]",
        ShiftStart: "",
        ShiftEnd: "",
        LocationActive: true,
        RoleActive: true
    };
    var child = new WorkShift(p, data);
    this.WorkSegments.push(child);
```